# jquery fullpage and IOS Safari issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using Alvaro fullpage plugin, and it works well.

But i have discovered some Iphone with IOS 9.2 and safari browser issue.

I have some code in afterLoad callback, it checks what slide is visible. If it's first slide, i am removing scroll-menu, and when slide is not first, i am adding this class.

And this works well, but on orientation change, IOS don't respect this callback.

Below my Javascript code for Fullpage plugin:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
    //Scrolling
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    autoScrolling: true,
    fitToSection: true,
    fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
    scrollBar: false,
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    //animateAnchor: true,
    recordHistory: true,
// Callback - issue on orientation change
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        if(index > 1){
            header.addClass("scroll-menu");
        }
        if(index == 1){
            header.removeClass('scroll-menu');
        }
    }
});
```

I don't have any idea, how to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *but on orientation change, IOS don't respect this callback.* It works as expected on the [callbacks example page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/callbacks.html).

Comment: try to add console.log(index) after header.addClass("scroll-menu") and header.removeClass('scroll-menu'). And then rotate device. Also, i said, that issue occurs on Safari on IOS. Chrome works good.

Comment: The callback will only get fired once, that's the expected behavior. Why would you want to check twice if you are in the 1st section? As I said, the callbacks example page is showing how it fires the correct callback.